# SQL Server: get SO number from a string in a specific column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table named "PONDAILY" which has a column named"PONCOM". "PONCOM" has string content like a text note from which I need to extract only the SO number from the string, below are the example of how the data in the columns looks and highlighted is what I am looking to retrieve. I can't use any UDF as I have only read access to SQL server.

```
DELETE TO EXPEDITE ON NEW STO FOR M/D SO SAP# **5000068**.  HN04

DELETING FOR M/D SO#**4500000762** KF 03-31

REDUCED BY 1 TO EXPEIDTE FOR M/D SO**100471**...CSR EM...HN04040

REDUCED QTY BY 1 TO EXPEDITE FOR M/D SO SAP **100551**. HN040300

REDUCED QTY BY 1 TO EXPEDITE FOR M/D SO SAP **100551**/1. HN040300

REDUCED BY QTY1 FOR M/D SO# **105707**

REDUCED QTY BY 3 FOR M/D SO#S **5003785**, 5003786, 5003791 KF 0
```

I would like to get only the contain in bold

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand question correctly:

```
select substring(PONCOM, t2.num, case when t3.not_num < t2.num then 8000 else t3.not_num - t2.num end)
  from PONDAILY p 
   cross apply (select charindex('SO', PONCOM, 1)) t1(so)
   cross apply (select patindex('%[0-9]%', substring(PONCOM, t1.so, 8000)) + t1.so - 1) t2(num)
   cross apply (select patindex('%[^0-9]%', substring(PONCOM, t2.num, 8000)) + t2.num - 1) t3(not_num)
```

Comment: I think it is working perfectly but i do not see output for lines like this :CCdddD 02, 7001032 hftfLIPS,SO**2300**.RW245588, SO# **1000471*** KFE 040400

Comment: it's strange, because I see result for this line: "CCdddD 02, 7001032 hftfLIPS,SO2300.RW245588, SO# 1000471* KFE 040400"

Comment: ok thanks alot.  can we avoid fields with only numbers as it returns only numbers in return. example 0085128558 is the fields value and column return value is 0085128558

Comment: Yes, need add a condition: where t1.so > 0